# Can I define variable in Julia just like in Fortran

Tags: julia

I am new to Julia. Have a quick question.
In Fortran, we can do

```
implicit none
```

Therefore whenever we use a variable, we need to define it first. Otherwise it will give error.

In Julia, I want to do the same time thing. I want to define the type of each variable first, like Float64, Int64, etc. So that I wish that Julia no longer need to automatically do type conversion, which may slow down the code.
Because I know if Julia code looks like Fortran it usually runs fast.

So, in short, is there a way in Julia such that, I can force it to only use variables whose types has been defined, and otherwise give me an error message? I just want to be strict.

I just wanted to define all the variables first, then use them. Just like Fortran does.

Thanks!

[Edit]

As suggested by the experts who answers the questions, thank you very much! I know that perhaps in Julia there is no need to manually define each variables one by one. Because for one thing, if I do that, the code will become just like Fortran, and it can be very very long especially if I have many variables.

But if I do not define the type of the each variables, is Julia smart enough to know the type? Will it do some conversions which may slow down the code?

Also, even if there is no need to define variables one by one, is there in some situations we may have to manually define the type manually?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible* as such. You can, however, add type annotations at any point in your code, which will raise an error if the variable is not of the expected type:

```
julia> i = 1
1

julia> i::Int64
1

julia> i = 1.0
1.0

julia> i::Int64
ERROR: TypeError: in typeassert, expected Int64, got a value of type Float64
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[4]:1

julia> i=0x01::UInt8
0x01
```

*Julia is a dynamically-typed language, though there are packages such as https://github.com/aviatesk/JET.jl for static type-checking (i.e., no type annotations required) and https://github.com/JuliaDebug/Cthulhu.jl for exploring Julia's type inference system.

Comment: Besides asserting types, you can also use `::` to [declare types for local variables](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Type-Declarations) (third paragraph down): "When appended to a variable on the left-hand side of an assignment, or as part of a `local` declaration, the `::` operator means something a bit different: it declares the variable to always have the specified type," but it's not what OP wants since it coerces assignments with `convert` and is not idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you! But if I do not define the type first, will that slow down the code? Because it seems Julia then may need to do conversion or something, and the code will slow down?

Comment: No, that is where type inference comes in (i.e., the compiler determining the types of variables). The key term usually used to describe this is *type stability* e.g. https://www.juliabloggers.com/writing-type-stable-julia-code/

Comment: @cbk Thank you. With your example, I want this,  i=1, then i::Int64, then if I do i=1.0, I want Julia to report error. because I already define i as Int64, I want i to keep Int64. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes and no. There are a few approaches 1) Add additional type annotations later in the code, so an error would be raised if the type had changed (makes code less general, but I suppose so would your desired solution). 2) use a static type checker like JET.jl to warn you, 3) Learn to recognize when code is or is not type stable, be sure not to change the type. Of these, 3 is really the most flexible and general, and what I would recommend getting comfortable with (perhaps plus some 2). Julia is a dynamically typed language, and fighting that is not really the best approach IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Strict type declaration is not how you achieve performance in Julia.
You achieve the performance by type stability.
Moreover declaring the types is usually not recommended because it decreases interoperability.

Consider the following function:

```
f(x::Int) = rand() < 4+x ? 1 : "0"
```

The types of everything seem to be known. However, this is a terrible (from performance point of view) function because the type of output can not be calcuated by looking types of input. And this is exactly how you write the performant code with regard to types.

So how to check your code? There is a special macro `@code_warntype` to detect such cases so you can correct your code:

[image]

Another type related issue are the containers that should not be specified by abstract elements. So you never want to have neither `Vector{Any}` nor Vector{Real} - rather than that you want `Vector{Int}` or Vector{Float64}.

See also https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/ for further discussion.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! Could you perhaps suggest some high performance Julia code examples? I just like to see how other people write Julia code. I am a Fortran guy and I am new to Julia, but Julia gives me a feeling that its grammar is similar with Python or R, it makes me feel that it is not a high performance language.  If I do not define the type of each variable clearly before using it, is Julia smart enough to automatically know the type? If it needs to do type conversion then the code will slow down, right? Thanks!

Comment: But on the other hand, if I declare each variable clearly before using it, then the code will look like Fortran, then I perhaps would rather write code in modern Fortran lol.

Comment: Start by running each single example in the performance tips https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/ . Benchmark them all yourself - after spending few hours with that you will have very good feeling on writing performant code. Adding type to just everything ruins Julia's multiple dispatch interoperability model so it is not a good idea in practical applications.

Comment: thank you very much indeed! OK, will check that. Yes, I was thinking it may not be smart in Julia to define types of each variables before using it. Because if I write it in this way, the code will be just like Fortran. If so, perhaps there is no need to use Julia.

Comment: by the way, do you know how the performance of Julia compared with modern Fortran? Assuming that they are both well written. I feel is that Julia can be much faster than Python and R, and can even replace them. But from performance point of view, it seems it may still not be able to compete with modern Fortran.

Comment: Check out https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/julia-fast-as-fortran-beautiful-as-python/1405. TLDR is that for well optimized code, Julia is typically about as fast (or sometimes a little faster since the open source Fortran compilers have worse special functions and vectcorization ability)

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel Thank you! Do you think that I can use  const as a way in Julia to enforce the type declaration? It looks like const is exactly what I want. It can define the type of a variable at the first place. At the same time, the value of a const variable can actually change. So one of the purpose of const seems just to set the type of a variable. This seems look like Fortran, in which the type of variable needs to be defined if we do implicit none.

Comment: yes you can. code using `const` does not suffer performance penalty compared to code with `global` variables. However yo do not have to - you can just wrap all variables as function arguments